# Overlay dialog is not getting re-positioned on scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

In the image its [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) Box on **top** of dialog box I have a Component(`MyNewDetailComponent`) which I am opening it through [Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) and I have set the `scrollOptions` to `reposition()`.

The Problem is while I am scrolling in my dialog component the Overlay component is not getting re-positioned.

Here is the `Code`

```
export class MyComponent{

    constructor(protected overlay: Overlay,
        protected scrollStrategyOptions: ScrollStrategyOptions,
        protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {

    const strategy = this.overlay.position()
    .connectedTo(cdkOverlayOrigin.elementRef, { originX: 'end', originY: 'bottom' }, { overlayX: 'end', overlayY: 'top' })
    .withOffsetX(5)
    .withOffsetY(0);


    const config = new OverlayConfig({ positionStrategy: strategy, scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition(), width: '285px', hasBackdrop: false });
    this.testOverlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);

    const componentReference = this.testOverlayRef.attach(
    new ComponentPortal(MyNewDetailComponent, this.viewContainerRef));

    this.testOverlayRef.updatePosition();

}
```

[image]

Comment: As per the [guidlines](https://material.io/components/dialogs/#behavior), `Most dialog content should avoid scrolling [...] Dialogs don’t scroll with elements outside of the dialog, such as the background`. Do you really need to make it scroll ? Also, please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Answer (score 4):

The Solutuion,

```
/** Time in milliseconds to throttle the scroll events. **/
const config = new OverlayConfig({ positionStrategy: strategy, scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition({scrollThrottle:10}), width: '285px', hasBackdrop: false });
```

Refer [RepositionScrollStrategy](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/7cd78ffc59c1975012b4a7913f147cedc9c97ae0/src/cdk/overlay/scroll/reposition-scroll-strategy.ts)  on Angular Material.

**Note:** The re-positioning in `ckd-overlay` component will happen based on the scroll 
          positioning of the Parent Window Scroll.